# Relation between journalling and commitment control

Tags: ibm-midrange

This question is specific to database files in an iSeries database. If a file is journalled, is commitment control mandatory when using the file in programs (updating and writing to the files)?

Comment: Commitment control is not mandatory. I once used journaling without commitment control as part of a backup/restore strategy to restore files from a weekly save of the file and a daily save of the journal receivers.

Answer (score 3):

No. Journaling does not require commitment control. However, commitment control requires journaling [(unless the file in question is only open for reading)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzakj/rzakjjrnfiles.htm).

I haven't been able to find an independent source which *explicitly* states that journaling does not require commitment control, but it is implied when discussing the process of setting up commitment control, such as in [this article](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg031109-story01.html). Clearly, you can set up journaling without setting up commitment control.

Comment: It's not uncommon to journal files for HA purposes or auditing; even if you have an application system that doesn't use commitment control.

Comment: Not only HA and auditing, but also recovery via APYJRNCHG/RMVJRNCHG. Not seen as often as in past years, but very useful when appropriate, e.g., after an application update that messes up applied transactions or when needing to rerun a process.

Answer (score -1):

The default is for commitment control when programs are created.  However, Commitment control is not mandatory.

Comment: When compiling with `CRTBNDRPG`, `CRTRPGMOD`, or `CRTRPG`, the default is no commitment control. You have to run `STRCMTCTL` before the program runs to get it. Only when compiling with `CRTSQLRPG` or `CRTSQLRPGI` is commitment control `*CHG` the default (and started when the program starts if necessary).

Comment: rpg is short for Archaic Program Generator.  With these anciceint programs you generally use a CL program to handle the commitment control before calling the RPG.  STRCMTCTL (start commitment control) ENDCMTCTL (end commitment control) or something went wrong (ROLLBACK).   Make a CL that STRCMTCTL calls the rpg program then have the CL call ROLLBACK.  Wow what a great test.

Comment: Not real sure what you are arguing about here. The answer to the OP question is NO for the reasons given by JohnY. I am just pointing out that your answer is incorrect because Commitment Control is not the default, you have to compile in a specific way, or execute the program in a specific (non-default) way to activate Commitment control. Maybe that isn't what you meant.

Comment: Not arguing.  Commitment control is default is creating new programs.

Comment: @danny117 Commitment control **is not default** nor can you even specify it as a configured default (except when creating SQL* objects). It must be explicitly coded. And RPG is indeed "ancient", but anyone still coding in RPG instead of current RPG IV probably has a good reason.

Comment: I see your point I just want the RPGer to learn how the world outside the box works and so does IBM.  Crtsql it defaults to *change.

Comment: @danny117 Agreed there. But the same can be said for almost any technology. We can find cases of "But I need the VB 6 IDE to run on Win10 64-bit and to create 64-bit apps!" Pick any OS and similar is out there. Still, we should push those stuck developers forward. IMO, not by claiming that a tool is "ancient" when actual problem is failure/inability/unwillingness to use modern features of very capable tools.